# Kafka, Re-Partitions, locality and ordering

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a question about re-partitioning in Kafka...

Let say I have a Topic which has 3 partitions on 3 Broker Kafka Cluster with replication factor 3, which will mean every Broker will have one partition for master and 2 other brokers will have the replication of this partition and I know inside of a partition, as long partition distribution strategy stay same, ordered delivery inside of the partition guaranteed.

My question is, lets say, I decide 3 partitions are not enough, I decide to add one more partition and one more broker, what will happen then? Would the message that are already in a partition would be transferred to new partition if the partition strategy say so or they will stay in the old partition and only the new records would be written to new partition?

If the all the partition will be re-arranged after the creation of new partition, will the order of delivery be preserved?

Answer (score 2):

> Be aware that one use case for partitions is to semantically partition data, a**nd adding partitions doesn't change the partitioning of existing data** so this may disturb consumers if they rely on that partition. That is if data is partitioned by hash(key) % number_of_partitions then this partitioning will potentially be shuffled by adding partitions but Kafka will not attempt to automatically redistribute data in any way.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_modify_topic

Comment: This brings up  a more interesting question, if I have a Kafka Stream application for above scenario, when I search a particular data that the key was previously pointing to partition 3, new partition added and it should be actually on partition 4 and the requests, while the partition strategy stay same and will point partition 4, will not be able to find the data?

Comment: I guess its one of situations when devs need to write their own Partitioner.java implementation, I haven't find any clues yet how to do that correctly.

Comment: You use Kafka Streams, let's say that you have 2 instances. In your scenario you have 3 partitions, so you will have 3 tasks that will be distribute on those 2 instances, let's say : 
    Instance 1 : [task_1]
    Instance 2 : [task_2, task_3]

Now you have 4 partitions, so you will have an other task (not sure if it's added automatically or if we need to restart the two apps) that will be distribute, here it will be placed in the instance 1 (so that's the load will be at least even).

Comment: The problem is not resolvable, you have data that was distributed in, let's say partition 1, and now are in partition 4, so for the same key, a portion of the data are in those two partitions.

Comment: Now it's depends on the topic and the app that you are developing, if your app read from this topic, and then doing some stuff and writing to an other sink topic, which the partitions number remains unchanged, then the data that was in partitions [1, 4] will continue to go to the same partition on the sink topic. 
But if your topic that you mentioned is actually the sink topic, then you will have to read message from this topic and writing to another one !